# The following code takes input in an unexpected way

Tags: c++, c

```
scanf("%d%d\n",&x,&y);
```

Can someone explain how the compiler compiles the line of code and explain it to me?

Comment: What part of it are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone explain how the compiler compiles the line of code and explain it to me?

1. It loads the source file into memory (maybe in parts).
2. The lexer breaks the line into preprocessor tokens.
3. The preprocessor tries to expand `scanf`, `x` and `y` with appropriate macros, hopefully these aren't defines so this is a NOP.
4. The preprocessor tokens are converted into tokens and the parser parses the line.
5. It does a name lookup to match `scanf`, `x` and `y` to the previously declared symbols.
6. It converts the above line to an abstract syntax tree or some other form of intermediate representation.
7. It does type checking.
8. It does high level optimization such as inlining.
9. The back-end converts the intermediate representation into machine code, possibly with more optimizations done on the machine code.
10. the result is written to an object-file that is later passed to the linker.

Of course this is very approximate and there are many variations for this process.

Now, which part of these you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

It's a call to the [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) function. The first argument is a format `%d%d\n`, which means "expect two decimal numbers followed by a newline".

Each `%d` there expects somewhere to write the result in memory. `&x` and `&y` basically mean "write it to the address of the `x` and `y` variables".

They're passed by *address* (`&x`) rather than value (`x`) because otherwise `scanf` wouldn't have access to the real location of `x` and be able to write to it.

Comment: The link goes to the sscan function.

Answer (score 0):

> how the compiler compiles

Well, I'm not eligible for that right now but if you are confused about the `\n` char, i can solve that mystry for you.

between [format specifiers](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output), if you enter any char, it is taken as delimiter within inputs.

```
scanf("%d%d\n",&x,&y);
```

it means, after entering two nums you've to hit `return` key to complete `scanf`.

```
scanf("%d\n%d\n",&x,&y);
```

it means, after entering each num you've to hit `return` key to complete `scanf`.

Now, about the `&x, &y` part:

Since user input needs to be stored into memory, you should paas `address` of variable where you want to store the user input.

In your example, you want to store first num into x; hence you pass the address of x, i.e. `&x`.

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

save this program as test.c file

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void){
    int x=0,y=0;
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    printf("x is %d, y is %d",x,y);
    }
```

compile like

```
gcc test.c
```

run as

```
./a.out
```

enter 10 and hit Enter key

again enter 20 and hit Enter key

**output will be**

x is 10, y is 20

I think you may be doing mistake in printing those value

Instead of `printf("x is %d, y is %d",x,y);`
you may be doing

```
 printf("x is %d, y is %d");
```

which will give you garvase value